# Elasticsearch - How to specify the same analyzer for search and index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm working on a Spanish search engine. (I don't speak Spanish) But based on my research, the goal is more or less like this: 1. filter stopwords like "dos","de","la"... 2. stem the words for both search and index. e.g If you search "primera", then "primero","primer" should also show up.

My attempt:

```
es_analyzer={
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "spanish_stop": {
                "type":       "stop",
                "stopwords":  "_spanish_" 
                },
                "spanish_stemmer": {
                "type":       "stemmer",
                "language":   "spanish"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "default_search": {
                    "type": "spanish"
                },
                "rebuilt_spanish": {
                "tokenizer":  "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "spanish_stop",
                    "spanish_stemmer"
                ]
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem:
When I use `"type":"spanish"` in the `"default_search"`, my query "primera" gets stemmed to "primer", which is correct, but even though I specified to use `"spanish_stemmer"` in the filter, the documents in the index aren't stemmed. So as a result when I search for "primera", it only shows exact matches for "primer". Any suggestions on fixing this?

Potential fix but I haven't figured out the syntax:

1. Using built-in `"spanish"` analyzer in filter. What's the syntax?
2. Adding spanish stemmer and stopwords in `"default_search"`. But I don't know how to use compound settings there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "spanish_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_spanish_"
        },
        "spanish_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "spanish"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "default_search": {
          "type":"spanish",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "spanish_stop",
            "spanish_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "title":{
        "type":"text",
        "analyzer":"default_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title": "primer"
}
{
  "title": "primera"
}
{
  "title": "primero"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "title":"primer"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64420517",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.13353139,
        "_source": {
          "title": "primer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64420517",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.13353139,
        "_source": {
          "title": "primera"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64420517",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.13353139,
        "_source": {
          "title": "primero"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one question, `"default_search"` is actually a keyword in Elasticsearch, not some custom analyzer I created, see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/specify-analyzer.html#specify-search-default-analyzer. Does that affect anything?

Comment: @XuekaiDu thanks for your reply :) Sorry, I was not aware that `default_search` is not your custom analyzer. But looking at the documentation, it is clear that it is a default search analyzer that can be set while creating an index. And, therefore to avoid this confusion, you must add `analyzer` setting (in the mapping)

Comment: @XuekaiDu analyzer setting (in the mapping) points to the `default_analyzer`(in your case) which will be used at index time. We can also add `search_analyzer` setting in the mapping if you want to use a different analyzer at search time. By default, queries will use the same analyzer (for `search_analyzer`) as that of the analyzer defined in the field mapping.

Comment: @XuekaiDu it will be better if you don't use `default_search` as the name of your custom analyzer (to avoid any confusion). However, it will not make any difference to your search result if you don't forget to add an analyzer setting in the mapping

Comment: @XuekaiDu please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, if it helped you resolve your issue 